# How to Buy Machu Picchu Tickets for Children Online?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, children, machu-picchu

**Now that you can no longer buy tickets for Machu Picchu at the gate to regulate quotas, how can one buy a ticket for children?**

The [official Machu Picchu site](http://www.machupicchu.gob.pe) says that children 8 and under a free and that older ones pay student price but the interface only has two options: *National Adults* and *Foreign Adults*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Ticket Machu Pichu](http://ticketmachupicchu.com/prices-of-machu-picchu-tickets/) site appears to allow online allows purchase of tickets for children (8-17 years old student rate), noting that you send a copy of their passport or identify document for verification.

Scroll down to the note: **Children between 8-17 years have student rate. Send a copy of your passport or identity document. Children under 8 are free.**

Comment: Is that for real? Looks like a rip-off. The official Adult price is $38 USD for foreigners and $19 USD for Andean members while that site has foreign students for $37 and Andean for $27, so their student rate is higher than the official adult rate!